# Emacs freezes on adding remote tramp path to ecb-source-path

Tags: emacs, tramp, emacs-ecb

I'm trying to add a remote directory to my ecb directory pane by modifying the `ecb-source-path` variable in my `.emacs` file under Emacs 24.2, ecb 2.40, OS X 10.8.2. The following works via tramp from within emacs:

```
   /username@server.com:/home/username
   /username@server:/home/username      (have set up an alias server->server.com)
   /server.com:/home/username           (username is same as local user, so can be omitted)
   /server:/home/username
```

I'm not sure whether I have the syntax wrong, but I've tried the following to add the path to ecb:

```
   (setq ecb-source-path (quote("/username@server.com:/home/username"))) (**)
   (setq ecb-source-path (quote("/server.com:/home/username")))
   (setq ecb-source-path (quote("/scpc:username@server.com:/home/username")))
```

Which cause emacs to hang when issuing `ecb-activate`, with no error messages displayed in the message buffer

```
   (setq ecb-source-path (quote("/username@server:/home/username")))
   (setq ecb-source-path (quote("/server:/home/username")))
   (setq ecb-source-path (quote("username@server.com:/home/username")))
```

Which result in message: `Warning: Source-path <ENTERED PATH> is not accessible - ignored!`

Has anyone done this and know the correct syntax for adding remote paths to `ecb-source-path`? According to the documentation, `(**)` should work. If the syntax is indeed correct, are there any tips for debugging what might be going on and causing emacs to freeze? Or is this an issue with ecb itself?